# enabling lz4 compression in zswap (ie, making zswap more efficient)

Tags: 16.04, kernel, performance, swap, compression

I'm trying to enable LZ4 compression for zswap on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

My GRUB config:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash elevator=cfq profile zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4 zswap.max_pool_percent=80"
```

I executed `sudo update-grub`, and rebooted. But, zswap says `compressor lz4 not available, using default lzo`. I have `liblz4-tool` installed. This is the message I get after executing `dmesg | grep zswap`

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=148a9e6d-52db-4678-b11d-ef1e5559b69d ro quiet splash elevator=cfq profile zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4 zswap.max_pool_percent=80 vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=148a9e6d-52db-4678-b11d-ef1e5559b69d ro quiet splash elevator=cfq profile zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4 zswap.max_pool_percent=80 vt.handoff=7
[    0.716485] zswap: compressor lz4 not available, using default lzo
[    0.716493] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
```

Comment: [Here's](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169585&p=2)  the steps on how to fix the same issue in Arch Linux.
Can anyone please help me do it in debian based os?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the solution in this [Russian Debian Forum](https://debianforum.ru/index.php?topic=9422.0). I had to run these extra steps

```
sudo su
echo lz4 >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo lz4_compress >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

And run `dmesg | grep -i zswap`, to see

```
[    0.715952] zswap: loaded using pool lz4/zbud
```

Excited to see how the performance improves.

**edit**:
I have written my steps in [this guide](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/enable-zswap-to-increase-performance/11302). You can check if you face issues enabling zswap.