# zswap: compressor lz4 not available, using default lzo

Tags: grub2, swap, initramfs, compression

After configuring `zswap` and running (for [enabling lz4 compression in zswap on the initramfs stage](https://askubuntu.com/a/877322/19753)):

```
sudo -s
echo lz4 >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo lz4_compress >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
update-initramfs -u
```

and

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash init=/bin/e4rat-lite-preload zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4"
```

in grub(and running `update-grub`)

the output of `dmesg | grep -i zswap` is

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-
generic.efi.signed root=UUID=9d2dfe9c-48af-4577-bfd0-fb484fa9aed5 
ro quiet splash init=/bin/e4rat-lite-preload zswap.enabled=1 
zswap.compressor=lz4 vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-
4.10.0-19-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=9d2dfe9c-48af-4577-bfd0-
fb484fa9aed5 ro quiet splash init=/bin/e4rat-lite-preload 
zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4 vt.handoff=7
[    0.971264] zswap: compressor lz4 not available, using default 
lzo
[    0.971286] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
```

How can I enable lz4?

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234721/zswap-can-never-find-required-modules-on-boot

Comment: Does `lsinitramfs` show the modules in the initrd?

Answer (score 3):

I think for some reason the module should be loaded before generating the initramfs.

Try the following, worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo modprobe -v lz4
sudo update-initramfs -u 
sudo reboot
```