# zswap can never find required modules on boot

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs, memory-usage

I've had no trouble with Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04, but I have recently span up a 20.04 VM and I cannot get it to set the correct Zswap parameters at boot. It would appear that it cannot find the required modules.

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i 'zs|zr|zc'
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1009-gcp root=PARTUUID=db157b59-599b-4c37-91f7-175253949aca ro console=ttyS0 transparent_hugepage=always zswap.compressor=lz4hc zswap.enabled=1 zswap.max_pool_percent=50 zswap.zpool=z3fold panic=-1
[    0.200636] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1009-gcp root=PARTUUID=db157b59-599b-4c37-91f7-175253949aca ro console=ttyS0 transparent_hugepage=always zswap.compressor=lz4hc zswap.enabled=1 zswap.max_pool_percent=50 zswap.zpool=z3fold panic=-1
[    2.062108] zswap: compressor lz4hc not available, using default lzo
[    2.064354] zswap: zpool z3fold not available, using default zbud
[    2.066454] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
```

However, I have set the relevant configuration files the same way as I always have done.

```
$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/modules 
z3fold
lz4hc
lz4hc_compress
```

And this seems to be picked up when building the initrd.

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -vu
Available versions: 5.4.0-1009-gcp
Keeping /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1009-gcp.dpkg-bak
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1009-gcp
Adding module /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp/kernel/mm/z3fold.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp/kernel/lib/lz4/lz4hc_compress.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp/kernel/crypto/lz4hc.ko
[...]
```

`lsinitrd` also shows that the modules have been copied into the initrd.

```
$ lsinitrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1009-gcp | egrep 'lz4|z3'
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         8201 Apr 10 18:35 usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp/kernel/crypto/lz4hc.ko
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root            0 May  3 11:08 usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp/kernel/lib/lz4
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        17017 Apr 10 18:35 usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp/kernel/lib/lz4/lz4hc_compress.ko
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        31673 Apr 10 18:35 usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp/kernel/mm/z3fold.ko
```

An `lsmod` when booted confirms that the modules have not been loaded, but manually enabling them is no problem.

```
# echo lz4hc >/sys/module/zswap/parameters/compressor
# echo z3fold >/sys/module/zswap/parameters/zpool
$ lsmod | egrep 'lz4|z3'
z3fold                 28672  1
lz4hc                  16384  18
lz4hc_compress         24576  1 lz4hc
```

```
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/pool_limit_hit:0
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/same_filled_pages_enabled:Y
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled:Y
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/max_pool_percent:50
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/compressor:lz4hc
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/zpool:z3fold
```

Yet the boot seems to have the same problem every time. I find it a little odd that nothing is printed in `dmesg` when I change the parameters here, but I don't know if that means anything.

I can write a script to do this *after* boot but this is obviously not the correct process.

Has anyone else come across this? Maybe there's been a kernel change which means it cannot find the modules?

Comment: Opened a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.2/+bug/2046059