# Apply z3fold to zswap

Tags: kernel, swap

To reduce the number of writes to my system's SSD, I enabled zswap, with zswap.zpool=z3fold as a kernel parameter to set the zswap allocator to z3fold. However, when the system runs, I get zbud for the zswap allocator instead. Investigating system logs shows that z3fold was not available to the kernel at startup, so it made do with zbud.

To get lz4 working in zswap, I did some configuration, creating a new startup ram image with lz4 in it so it was available to the kernel at startup. Do I have to do something similar for z3fold?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a while, I managed to figure it out. Yes, it's very much like [enabling lz4 compression in zswap](https://askubuntu.com/a/877322).

Recalling how to enable lz4 compression:

> sudo su
> echo lz4 >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
> echo lz4_compress >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
> update-initramfs -u

I did a similar procedure to enable z3fold:

> sudo su
> echo z3fold >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
> update-initramfs -u

Pass zswap.zpool=z3fold into the kernel paramaters, and z3fold should be up and running.